# Nginx is running and configured but no connections can be made

Tags: nginx, fedora

I just did a fresh nginx install on Fedora 14 (yum install nginx) and got it configured with the following server inclusion:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    root        /var/www/html/test;
    server_name testserver.turnleftllc.com;

    location / {
        index   index.htm;
    }
}


ps aux | grep nginx
    root      1986  0.0  0.7  98056  1952 ?        Ss   18:55   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
    root      1987  0.0  1.0  98584  2656 ?        S    18:55   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

However, when pointing my browser to that domain name, it just hangs and then comes back with "Could not connect..."

The permissions for everything in /var/www/html is set to 775.  I've been running nginx on another server for a long while and never encountered this issue. It was always very easy in the past. Any thoughts on what's causing this?

I'm sure it's painfully obvious and I'll feel like a total moron when I figure out what it is.

---

```
[root@resolution ~]# iptables -L -n -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 3051  243K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    2    96 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22
  139  7251 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 2610 packets, 341K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

[root@resolution ~]# lsof -i -P | grep :80
nginx   1986 root    7u  IPv4   9807      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx   1987 root    7u  IPv4   9807      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
```

Comment: What do you get from `lsof -i -P | grep :80`?

Comment: done. results posted above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two hypotheses come to mind.

Firstly, that name resolution isn't working.  Could you do a `dig testserver.turnleftllc.com` on the client (or OS-equivalent, if the client's not running linux) and confirm that the IP address of the nginx server is returned?

Secondly, that the F14 box is firewalling.  Could you do an `iptables -L -n -v` on the F14 server and post the results as an edit above?

Not that this is in any way relevant to the question, but could I gently remind you that F14 is now out of support, and you shouldn't think of deploying any kind of production system on it?

Comment: Dig turns up the IP address without any issue. That was my first thought also. Other will be posted above as requested momentarily. And regarding f14: sadly, it's not up to me. Our IT department has decreed that this is what this server will be using.

Comment: @TomThorogood iptables it is; your `INPUT` chain is only accepting TCP port 22 (SSH).  You'll need to add 80.

Comment: Thanks, @Shane. I have no idea how to do that. That is new to me.

Comment: Something along these lines: `iptables -I INPUT 4 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT`